# Putting first X images in a different container from last Y images

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, each

This seems so simple, but can't think through it... I have a list of 13 images (`@images`), and I'm calling them in the view as such:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-left: 50px;">
<% @images.each do |image, key| %>
    <div class="col-xs-1" id="<%= "#{image}" %>"> 
        <%= image_tag("Portrait thumbnails/#{image}.jpg", class: "img-responsive thumbnail", alt: "#{image}", title: "#{image}") %>
        <h6><%= "#{image}" %></h6>
    </div>
<% end %>
</br>
```

The problem is that because 13 images don't fit horizontally, I'd like to break these into two rows of 6 and 7 images. How do I do that? I tried:

- `each_with_index` but since the index is also looped over, I can't put a container that is outside the index portion
- `@images.first(6)` as a temp solution, but then I realized that since this flattens the Hash into an array, it doesn't work for `@images.last(7)`

**Even more ideal,** I'd like a solution that scales, meaning that the program automatically counts the number of images, and divvies up into 6 per `col-xs-12` row. I know I can manually do this by just making a different instance variable for each set of 6 images, but that is way too manual there must be a programmatic way I'm just not thinking of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_slice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) for this.

```
<% @images.each_slice(6) do |images| %>  # Split into slices of 6
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <% images.each do |image| %> # Loop through each item in the slice 
      <div class="col-xs-1">
        .. 
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```